# How to Run Sympy_gama in windows 10 on localhost

Tags: python, django, sympy

I am new to python and django. I want to run sympy_gama on my localhost server. i follow the documentation given by 
sympy_gama [ https://github.com/sympy/sympy_gamma ].

but in some steps the error can be occurs. after a  `python deploy.py --generate-only --generate-test 1000` the  **../google_appengine/dev_appserver.py .** not working this command.

**Error is :**

```
../google_appengine/dev_appserver.py
'..' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

anyone can help me?

Comment: @krcools hello sir, can u help me to solved this error

Comment: @asv hello sir, can u help me to solved this error